# Proper pandas map syntax with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I know I'm almost there, but can't figure out the faster syntax for the equivalent of the below code:

```
def is_evening(df):
    lst = []
    for i in df.index:
        val = df["localized_time"][i]
        if val != 'NA':
            if val.hour >= 17 and val.hour <= 3:
                lst.append(1)
            else:
                lst.append(0)
        else:
            lst.append(-1)
    df["is_evening"] = lst
    return df
```

If it was just two values it would be easy, but with the additional conditions and stuff, is there a fast way to do this using pandas map?

What I have so far:

```
mask = [df["localized_time"] != 'NA']
df["is_evening"] = df["is_evening"] = df["localized_time"][mask].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x.hour >= 17 and x.hour <= 23) else 0)
# Doesn't seem to work
```

Could anyone help me out? Thank you! :)

Comment: I can't imagine when `val.hour >= 17 and val.hour <= 3` would be `True` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Holy crap tired coding does not help, thank you for spotting that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there definitely is:

```
def f(x):
    return int(x.hour >= 17 and x.hour <= 3) if x != 'NA' else -1

df["is_evening"] = df["localized_time"].apply(f)
```

So here `f` is a function that maps a *single* `localized_time` element to an `is_evening` element. We can also use a lambda expression, but this will be more ugly:

```
df["is_evening"] = df["localized_time"].\
    apply(lambda x: int(x.hour >= 17 and x.hour <= 3) if x != 'NA' else -1)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Note that while this is more concise, it still uses Python-level functions instead of vectorized operations.